# Is there a way to view the actual HTML elements that are being captured by the Selectors?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am trying to determine if my Selector is capturing the correct HTML elements.  The only thing that is being outputted is the Selector object which doesn't tell me anything.

I tried to put a debugger in VScode and use the console to view the Selector.

For example if I have this HTML,

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my Selector is as followed...
const h1 = Selector('h1');

Is there a way for me to see the HTML of the captured element?  Eg; have to output

```html
<h1>This is a test</h1>?
```

Comment: console.log(h1);

Comment: Logging of TestCafe Selector will not provide any useful information since TestCafe Selector is a complex object that initially does not contain html code.


For TestCafe you can use the following approach:


    const html = await Selector('h1').innerText;
    console.log(html);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging a Selector object in debug mode is quite difficult.
The best way I found to check if a Selector is correct is to hover over it before doing any action or assertion:

```
const h1 = Selector('h1');
await t
  .hover(h1)
  ...
```

Then you should see the big cursor moving and hover over the selector.